# What is wrong with the following statement in my code behind in homepage.master?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create a querystring so when a user switches languages, the URL changes to ?lang=NL, for example.  I have this in the code behind on homepage.master (VB, NOT C#):

```
  Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Then
```

Visual Studio underlines it in blue.  When I hover over the left side of the statement, it says "Property Value Must Assign to the property or use its value"  When I hover over the right side of the erred statement, it says, "End of Statement Expected".

I'm not sure if the code I was given is C#, but when I use the Teleflex translator to check, it says "EOF Expected" and won't translate.

All of this is tied into 3 classes I created, BasePage.vb, Culture.vb, and Global.vb.  But I think it's just this line that's screwing everything up.  If anybody knows the solution, I'd sincerely appreciate you sharing it with me, 'cause this is frustrating.  Thanks!

---

p.s.:  If necessary, here's my entire homepage.master.vb:

```
  Partial Public Class Homepage

Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    If Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Is Nothing OrElse _

    Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Then

        RequestLanguageChange(Me.Request.QueryString("lang"))

    End If

End Sub



Protected Sub RequestLanguageChange(ByVal culture As String)



    'store requested language as new culture in the session

    Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) = culture



    'reload last requested page with new culture

    Server.Transfer(Request.Path)

End Sub

Private Function [Global]() As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function

  End Class
```

Comment: Just as a test, try replacing the [Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE with the actual string value that it represents and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting the following two lines on a single line:

```
If Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Is Nothing OrElse _

    Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Then
```

Like:

```
If Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Is Nothing OrElse Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Then
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew.  Your solution got rid of the error in Visual Studio.  When I ctrl/F5 to run the page, it says "The method or operation is not implemented.".  So I'm guessing that it has something to do with one of my classes -- BasePage.vb, Global.vb, or Culture.vb.  But your suggestion did get rid of that error.  Thanks a lot for your time, Matthew!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the space between these two lines...

```
    If Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Is Nothing OrElse _

           Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Then
```

Make it read like

```
    If Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Is Nothing OrElse _
           Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Then
```

Comment: Hello Rahul.  Indeed, when I moved the lines together, Visual Studio didn't show an error anymore, so that worked.  When I pressed ctrl/F5 to run the page, it said "The method or operation is not implemented", so I think it has something to do with one of the classes I used to localize my site -- Global.vb, BasePage.vb, or Culture.vb.  But thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question -- I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

There should be **no** extraspace after line break in VBNet. Remove the extraspace after `_`.

```
If Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) Is Nothing OrElse _
    Me.Request.QueryString("lang") <> Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE) _
Then
```

Comment: Thank you John.  I see your point now.  When I eliminate the whitespace between lines, the Visual Studio errors go away.  Unfortunately, it still says "Method or operation is not implemented" when I control/F5 the page, so I'm thinking it has to do with one of the classes I created for localization -- culture.vb, basepage.vb, or global.vb.   Thanks a ton for your help -- it's great advice!